# British citizen - Remote work in UK for French company

Tags: france, eu, work-permit

I am a British citizen and have a 90-day fixed term contract with a French company. Do I need a French work permit in order to work remotely from the UK?

Answer (score 2):

As littleadv's answer correctly states, French immigration law doesn't apply and you don't need any kind of permit to be working in Britain as a British citizen.

If you are an employee (i.e. not working freelance or a contractor), your French employer might however struggle to accommodate you and follow all the tax and payroll procedures without a French address. They need to report your hiring to the tax and welfare agencies (*déclaration préalable à l'embauche*) and they are also legally liable to check that people they hire in France have the relevant permits.

I am not familiar enough with the procedure to know if there is a way to circumvent it or explicitly hire someone abroad but I wouldn't expect the average HR person to know either so you really need to double-check with them that they understand the specifics of your situation and do not expect you to show up with a French residence permit.

You also ought to worry about the tax and insurance implications on the British side. You may know more than I do about that and it may not be an issue from your perspective but I have also heard about employers refusing to hire people in your situation (physically present in another country) because they are afraid it would create some liability for them and they don't want to go through the trouble of figuring it out so that's another thing to clear with them as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

> I am a British citizen & have a 90-day fixed term contract with a French company. Do I need a French work permit in order to work remotely from the UK?

You're outside the French jurisdiction. You only need to comply with the laws of the country you're in or citizen of. So no, you don't.

Comment: You need a work permit in the country where you physically are. If you worked for a UK company and decided to rent a place in the French countryside for three months, you’d need a French work permit. If they know about it.